# Descriptive word very pleasantly surprised?

Tags: synonyms

What would be a single word to describe a very pleasantly surprised reaction?

Answer (score 0):

**wonderment**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wonderment)

> Something that produces wonder; a marvel

.

Answer (score 0):

The noun [**admiration**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/admiration) usually means *to have a feeling of great respect for a person or thing*, but another meaning that this word has would be *pleasurable contemplation* which can certainly be used to describe a situation where somebody is pleasantly surprised to see something or someone. Take a look at these two example sentences:

> They were lost **in admiration** of the scenery.
>
> Her eyes widened **in admiration** when she saw Enrique Iglesias, her idol, look back at her.